# How to change the file extension in files in a list

Tags: python, list, subdirectory, os.walk

I have this code for opening a folder with these directories. Some of them have the extension html but not all of them. How can I change all the files in my three subdirectories that do not have an extension html in .html ?

```py
from os import walk
mypath = ("/directory/path/to/folder")
f = []
for (dirpath,dirnames,filenames) in walk(mypath):
    f.extend(filenames)
    print(f)
```

Comment: Did any of the answers helped you? If so, please mark one as accepted. This way you will help other people with the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on Python 3.4 or higher, consider using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

Here is a solution for your problem using that:

```
from pathlib import Path

mypath = Path('/directory/path/to/folder')

for f in mypath.iterdir():
    if f.is_file() and not f.suffix:
        f.rename(f.with_suffix('.html'))
```

If you need to walk down to sub-directories as well, you can use the [`Path.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) method to list all directories recursively and then process each file in that directory. Something like this:

```
from pathlib import Path

mypath = Path('/directory/path/to/folder')

for dir in mypath.glob('**'):
    for f in dir.iterdir():
        if f.is_file() and not f.suffix:
            f.rename(f.with_suffix('.html'))
```

And here is one more way to walk down all directories and process all files:

```
from pathlib import Path

mypath = Path('/directory/path/to/folder')

for f in mypath.glob('*'):
    if f.is_file() and not f.suffix:
        f.rename(f.with_suffix('.html'))
```

Using [`Path.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) with two asterisks will list all sub-directories and with just one asterisk it will list everything down that path.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

First, write an image path generator with the following function.

```
import os

def getimagepath(root_path):
    for root,dirs,filenames in os.walk(root_path):
        for filename in filenames:
            yield(os.path.join(root,filename))
```

Input your folder path into the function. Then run a for loop checking the name for ending with html, then change the name with os.rename

```
paths = getimagepath("............................")
for path in paths:
    if not path.endswith('.html'):
         os.rename(path,path+'.html')
```

Comment: Might be better off with `if not path.endswith('.html')`. Also check for the `.` as well encase you get a file name like `mynamehtml`

Answer (score 1):

Call this function with your path.

```
import os
import os.path


def ensure_html_suffix(top):
    for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(top):
        for filename in filenames:
            if not filename.endswith('.html'):
                src_path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                os.rename(src_path, f'{src_path}.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ff = []
for (dirpath,dirnames,filenames) in os.walk(mypath):
    for f in filenames:
        if not f.endswith(".html"): #check if filename does not have html ext
            new_name = os.path.join(dirpath,f+".html")
            os.rename(os.path.join(dirpath,f),new_name) #rename the file
            ff.append(f+".html")
        else:
            ff.append(f)
    print(ff)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rename only a specific suffix, do the following:

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('./dir')

for f in path.iterdir():
    if f.is_file() and f.suffix in ['.txt']:
        f.rename(f.with_suffix('.md'))
```